# WPF: overlapping grid controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, grid

I am trying to build this in WPF (this was done in winform):
[image]

But the result looks like this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Test" />
        </Menu>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Header="Interfaces" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,-155,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="236" Width="419">
                </GroupBox>

                <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Header="Messages" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,-155,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="236" Width="419">
                </GroupBox>

                <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Header="Responses" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,-155,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="236" Width="419">
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <RichTextBox Name="txtLog" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph FontSize="12">Hello, world!</Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```

I can't understand why the text box overlaps the Group boxes from column 0. I'd like it to fill the grid on the right.

SO want's me to add more text: I'll probably want to add a GridSplitter at the center so help with that will also be appreciated.

Comment: get rid of negative right Margin "-155" on GroupBox. make it 0. Also it likely that you need to set `*` for Width and Height of rows and columns in second grid (`<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">`)

Comment: You might also want to remove the Width and Height from the GroupBoxes. So that your UI can adapt to any window size.

Comment: I didn't notice it there. It was added automatically when I dragged the groupbox on the form. That will teach me not to be lazy next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can simplify your `DockPanel` so that it can adhere to any screensize. I removed lot of unwanted stuff.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Test" />
    </Menu>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Interfaces" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Header="Messages" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Header="Responses" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <RichTextBox Name="txtLog" Margin="5">
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph FontSize="12">Hello, world!</Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

And Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@ASh is right. The negative value `-155` is somewhat confusing, it enables the `GroupBoxes` on the left panel take up wider place than their containing `Grid`.

So it is not the `RichTextBox` overlaps with the `GropuBoxes`; the `RichTextBox` is where it should be, it is the three `GroupBoxes` stretch right by 155 pixels.

And for the `RichTextBox`, since you put it in a `Grid` whose `Width` is set as `Auto`, so the `RictTextBox` does not stretch out horizontally to take up all the available space.

Remove these lines will fix this issue.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >

    <!--Remove the RowDefinitions/ColumnDefinitions-->           

    <RichTextBox Name="txtLog">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph FontSize="12">Hello, world!</Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```